# How to use mutable state in a loop?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The loop:

```
impl State {    
    pub fn exec(&mut self) -> Vec<(&[u8], SocketAddr)> {
        vec!()
    }
}

fn main_loop(mut state: State) {
    let mut packets = Vec::<(&[u8], SocketAddr)>::new();
    loop {
        let new = state.exec();
        packets.extend(new);
    }
}
```

gives the error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `state` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:93:14
   |
93 |             let new = state.exec();
   |                       ^^^^^ `state` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

Yet if I comment-out the `packets.extend(new);` line, there is no error.

I *think* the problem is that the returned vector is owned by `state`, as if `new` is dropped before the loop iterates, it's fine.  I'm happy for the returned vector to be copied, if this would fix it.

I expected that adding `.clone()` to either `new` or `state.exec()` would have fixed it, but it doesn't.

Is there a simple way of fixing this?

Or do I need to structure single-threaded application state in a different way?

Comment: You might try returning a reference to the vector maybe?

Comment: @mousetail I think that any references, returned by methods of a mutable state, stop loops from compiling.  Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Does `exec` need to take `&mut self`? Could you maybe have two separate methods, one that does the mutations, and one that returns the slice, the latter taking `&self`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
pub fn exec(&mut self) -> Vec<(&[u8], SocketAddr)>
```

Let's add in the [implicit lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision)

```
pub fn exec<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Vec<(&'a [u8], SocketAddr)>
```

So the returned slice must have *the same* lifetime as the mutable borrow. Now, what do you do with the returned slice?

```
let new = state.exec();
packets.extend(new);
```

We store it in `packets`. So the borrow of `state` must last at least at long as the type of `packets`, which is the whole function. Hence, from the first iteration of the loop to the very end of the function, we can never borrow `state` again, since the mutable borrow lasts until the end of the function.

The first question to ask yourself is: do you really need a mutable borrow? If you can get down to `&self`, then do that and your problem is solved. Otherwise, you'll need to restructure things somehow. The type `&[u8]` is inherently unowned. It's a reference to *someone else's* data. If the only way you have to get that data is through `&mut self`, then you'll never be able to loop the way you want. So to clone the data, you'll need to use `to_vec`, which turns `&[u8]` into `Vec<u8>` (your type signatures will have to change to reflect this).

Comment: Thanks, that's a very clear explanation.  I'd worked out, by experimentation, that the `&[u8]` was the issue.  This explains why.

Comment: " since the mutable borrow lasts until the end of the function" weel same for no mutable borrow on this case, maybe this sentence is misleading. With a non mutable borrow in the loop code will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just changing the function signature so that the returned `&[u8]` does not borrow from `*self` will allow the example code to compile:

```
    pub fn exec<'a>(&mut self) -> Vec<(&'a [u8], SocketAddr)> {
        vec![]
    }
```

Note that `'a` is a free lifetime parameter, so the caller can supply anything there (including `'static`) and whatever references `exec` returns will have to satisfy the caller-supplied lifetime. In practice, this means that the `Vec` can only contain `'static` references, because `'static` is the only lifetime that is a subtype of every other lifetime.

It's unlikely this is what you want. However, it might be, or the `[u8]` might be borrowed from some other argument (not `*self`), or re-borrowed from a reference contained in `*self`. This shows that simply changing the signature to more accurately represent the lifetime relationships between inputs and outputs can sometimes fix errors like this one without any other changes.

Comment: Thanks, that's really added to my understanding.  Default lifetimes aren't always what we need.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is:

```
impl State {    
    pub fn exec(&mut self) -> Vec<(Vec<u8>, SocketAddr)> {
        vec!()
    }
}

fn main_loop(mut state: State) {
    let mut packets = Vec::<(Vec<u8>, SocketAddr)>::new();
    loop {
        let new = state.exec();
        packets.extend(new);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure that this is the best solution, so I'll leave the question open for a while.